# Select2 search highlights results based on option value

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 to let the user select among a list of email addresses. The option value is the actual email address, while the option html display the full name (and again the email address).

```
<select>
       <option value="test@mail.com">Test Mail [test@mail.com]</option>
       ...
<select>
```

What happens is that the user types the email address (eg. test@email.it) and Select2 finds a possible match, but since it's not exactly the same as the html, it doesn't automatically highlight the first match.

Therefore I would like Select2 to highlight (preselect) the search results based on the value or, as an alternative, to always highlight the first result of a search if present.

Does anybody know how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: no ajax is used?

Comment: No, the options are already there